# Algorithm for finding integer solutions for linear inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, computer-science

Given $b_i,c_{i,j}\in \mathrm N^+, R_i(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)=\sum_jc_{i,j}X_j$ :

> $0< R_1(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) < b_1$
>
> $0< R_2(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) < b_2$
>
> ...
>
> $0< R_n(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) < b_n$

Want to find all integer solutions with $0<x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4$

Is there a general algorithm to find integer solutions for these kind of inequalities?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Integer (Linear) Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) with a constant objective function, i.e. $\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{0}$ (the ILP $\mathbf{c}$, not your $c$, of course). However, ILP is NP-hard, but if you have not more than a few hundred variables you should be fine with today's solvers.

I'm also not sure about finding all the solutions in the existing frameworks but [this](https://opus4.kobv.de/opus4-zib/files/1063/ZR_08_09.pdf) small paper is aimed to that task and it should be theoretically possible.

Answer (score 1):

The following articles present an algorithm for describing the integer solutions of any system of linear equations and inequalities

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-66320-3_17
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-66320-3_18

This algorithm is implemented in Maple and the code can be
obtained from the download page of the following web site

http://regularchains.org/

Section 2.6 of the documentation shows a few examples

http://regularchains.org/Documentation/Polyhedra_worksheet.pdf

As you can see, the integer points of the input polyhedron are decomposed into so-called Z-polyhedra. Each of those has at least one integer point and enjoys a natural "lifting" property: every integer point in a projection of that Z-polyhedron can be lifted to an integer point of that Z-polyhedron. In general, arbitrary polyhedra do not have that property.